# Use LDAP objectClass to determine roles

Tags: 7, users, authentication-authorization

I'm currently working on a portal site in D7 that allows access to several applications. I have created blocks that link to those applications and made them visible to certain Drupal-roles.

My users are maintained in an LDAP directory and access to the applications is determined by an objectClass, i.e. a user with access to application app1 and app2 will have:

```
ObjectClass: app1-user
ObjectClass: app2-user
```

How can I configure Drupal to map those objectclasses to roles?

Comment: Are you using the LDAP module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap )? that supports role mapping